# SQLite query with - || OR. Concatenated results

Tags: sqlite, concatenation

I have a problem with the following query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT city || strftime("%Y", begintime) FROM Texts_original1
```

The query itself works but results themselves are concatenated so instead of for example :

```
city = Dublin 
strftime("%Y", begintime) = 2008
```

I get :

```
city || strftime("%Y", begintime) = Dublin2008
```

Any ideas how to avoid that concatenation and make the response be separated to different columns ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The || operator is "concatenate" - it joins together the two strings of its operands. ([Source](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html))

So, whatever it is you're trying to do, the `||` operator isn't what you want.

Comment: Ah yeah, you are right, I needed that only for count function to work. Without the || it works perfectly. I Copy-pasted the query with few changes, and I thought I still need ||. Thanks!

Comment: @user1125518 Include sample data and expected output in your question, you're not making it clear what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

change `||` by a `comma` to make it different columns. what happens if you try to execute this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT city, strftime("%Y", begintime) 
FROM Texts_original1
```

you tried to mention this: ***how to avoid that concatenation and make the response be separated to different columns***